# Pourquoi l'usage du verbe aimer n'admet pas l'article partitif ?

Tags: verbes, articles, partitif

En étudiant l'article partitif, spécialement avec les verbes manger et avoir, je me suis aperçu de l'absence de son usage avec le verbe aimer. Avec aimer on dit: **j'aime les biscuits**, par exemple, tandis qu'on pourrait dire **je mange des biscuits**.

Pourquoi ne s'utilise-t-il pas avec le verbe aimer ?

Y a-t-il d'autres exceptions ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

L'article partitif est employé pour désigner une certaine quantité indénombrable. Son emploi est donc dépendant du sens du verbe dont dépend le nom qu'il précède.

- Je mange trois/ quelques/ des/  biscuits.
- Je veux trois/ quelques/ des / fleurs.
- J'achète trois/ quelques/ des livres.

Par contre quand on parle de ses goûts on n'exprime pas à la suite une certaine quantité de la chose dont on parle. On emploie l'article défini.

- J'aime les fleurs.
- J'adore les choux.
- Je déteste les voyages.

Comment: +1 Tu expliques le pourquoi.

Comment: Merci! Peut-être que je suis trompé, mais je pensais que l'emploi du verbe manger plus le partitif pourrait exprimer le goût aussi. Quelque chose comme: Je ne mange pas des biscuits (je le déteste, son gout n'est pas bon).

Comment: @OrfeoAgenorMolino Dans ce cas on dit *je ne mange pas **de** biscuits*. Règle: « Lorsqu’ils se trouvent dans une phrase négative avec ne… pas, ne… plus, etc., l’article indéfini (un, une, des) et l’article partitif (du, de la, des) sont habituellement réduits à de (ou d’) devant le complément direct. » Mais manger  n'exprime pas vraiment un goût.

Answer (score 3):

Effectivement, on n'utilise pas l'article partitif mais l'article défini après "aimer".

C'est aussi le cas général avec les verbes d'appréciation :

- adorer
- admirer
- choisir
- détester
- préférer
- ...

Réf. : [nouvelobs.com](https://la-conjugaison.nouvelobs.com/fle/les-articles-partitifs-les-quantites-32.php)

Comment: Attention quand je dis *je choisis/préfère des salades (qui ne soient pas abîmées)*, le *des* est bien un *des* partitif (on peut remplacer par un nombre). Par contre *je préfère/choisis les salades* quand on fait une comparaison (entre les salades et les ..... choux).

Comment: @None Oui, j'avais même mis les cas *je préfère les biscuits/je préfère des biscuits* dans ma première réponse mais je l'ai rapidement supprimé et simplement indiqué *dans le cas général*. L'article défini est aussi possible avec aimer etc. : *j'aimerais de la salade*

Comment: Quand on dit *j'aimerais* le sens est me semble-t-il  tout de suite perçu comme n'exprimant pas  ses goûts/ses préférences qu'en général ça ne fait pas hésiter les apprenants. (j'aimerais=je veux).